# How to add placeholder while focusout for all the fields in form?

Tags: jquery, html, css, textinput

```
$('*').focus(function(){
$(this).removeAttr("placeholder");
});
```

This is used to work for all the fields in my form. But I'm not able to find how to add.

```
$('*').focusout(function(){
$(this).attr("placeholder","abc"); 
}
```

This is used for an individual field, but I need for all the fields commonly like hide and show

Comment: you can use each() function. Read the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why are you removing that attribute in the first place? Did you do it that way simply because it's more straight-forward than needing to use all of the several vendor-specific CSS ways of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not verry optimised but it work

```js
$('*:input').each(function(){
$(this).data('placeholder',$(this).attr("placeholder"))
$(this).removeAttr("placeholder");
$(this).on('focus', function(){
 $(this).attr("placeholder", $(this).data('placeholder'));
});
$(this).on('focusout', function(){
 $(this).removeAttr("placeholder");
});
});
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer. but my form contains all types of fields like input, select,textarea. and each feild has different placeholder.

Comment: hmm ok i changed it, `:input` is compatible with textareas, but selects dont have placeholder

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aopg7fh5/1/) example, when you *focusout* any *field*, the *placeholder* for all inputs change.

```
<form id="form">
  <p>Form</p>
  <p><input/></p>
  <p>
    <select>
      <option id="selectPlaceholder"></option>
      <option>Option 1</option>
      <option>Option 2</option>
      <option>Option 3</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p><textarea></textarea></p>
  <p>
    <button id="reset" type="button">Reset placeholder</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

---

```
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#form {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

input, select, textarea {
  width: 90%;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

---

```
$("input, select, textarea").focusout(function(){

    $("input, select, textarea").attr(
        'placeholder',
        'Text for the placeholder focusout'
    )
    $("#selectPlaceholder").html('Text for the placeholder focusout');

});

$('#reset').click(function(){
    $('input, select, textarea').removeAttr('placeholder');
    $('#selectPlaceholder').html('');
});
```